# Конвертирование binary to base8 (octal)

Tags: java

Требуется кодер-декодер массив байт, в стандарт чисел base8 (числа от 0..7)
1 - на входе должен быть массив байт
2 - переделываем в двоичный вид
3 - дробим по 3 цифры и переводим в соответствующее десятичное число

**Пример:**
Вход: 110 001 010 100 011 010
Выход: 612432

**Исключения:**
Если 3 двоичные цифры не набираются то, 
заменять на 1xx = 49 или 11x = 68 где,
1xx = 1+xx
1 = 100 = 4
xx = 9 (помечаем девяткой два добавленных в конец ноля)

и

11x = 11+x
11 = 110 = 6
x = 8 (помечаем восьмёркой один добавленный ноль)

**Пример**
Вход: 110 001 010 100 011 11  (на последних цифрах не набралось 3х для кодирования в base8)
Выход: 6124368 (8 помечает, что к 6 при кодировании был добавлен один бинарный ноль)

**Пример2**
Вход: 110 001 010 100 011 1  (на последних цифрах не набралось 3х для кодирования в base8)
Выход: 6124349 (9 помечает, что к 4 при кодировании было добавлено два бинарных ноля)

Comment: а обратно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зачем изобретать велосипед и показывать свое незнание radix вычислений?

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[]={...}; //составляем массив байтов
BigInteger bigInteger = new BigInteger(bytes);
//форматируем до бинарной строки
String s = bigInteger.toString(2);      
//форматируем до 8-тиричной строки
s = bigInteger.toString(8);         
//форматируем до 16-тиричной строки
s = bigInteger.toString(16);
```